# How to apply styles on Google Places Autocomplete UI (full-screen) control on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I've added the [Google Places Autocomplete UI control](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) in full-screen mode in my iOS application. Is there any way i can change the navigation bar's background color/tint color in this control?

I have also tried adding a new view controller in my application in an attempt to have better control on the styling. In this new view controller I have my navigation bar with the styles i want, and then added a UISearchController positioned at the top of the view (below the navigation bar). I linked this search controller with a results controller as described in the API docs here:

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_results_controller

However, as soon as i start typing something in the search bar, the results view hides the navigation bar.

I've also added the below code (again as described in the API docs), but it doesn't help either:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    // This makes the view area include the nav bar even though it is opaque.
    // Adjust the view placement down.
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I think the Autocomplete control only works properly when used in a navigation controller based app. I didn't have one. Now that I've added the navigation controller, the global styles for navigation bar and status bar which i had already defined in app delegate seem to affect the autocomplete modal as expected. The other issue where the navigation bar would get hidden completely as soon as i typed anything in the search box seems to have been fixed as well with the inclusion of navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest release of the Autocomplete control (1.11.1, run `pod update` in your project to make sure you have the latest version) you can tint the navigation bar in a [`GMSAutocompleteViewController`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller) using the appearance proxy, for example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

This should work whether or not you're using navigation controllers elsewhere in your app.